# iOS: Cannot handle space or lines breaks on Open gmail app using NSURL Scheme

Tags: ios, swift, gmail, url-scheme

We are working on an iOS app and we are using the Gmail app's URL Scheme to compose a new email for the user. We figured out most of it, however we are having some trouble adding new lines in the body of the email. So far our URL looks like this:

```
googlegmail://co?from=username@example.com&to=helpdesk@example.com&subject=TITLE&body=What%20ever%20they%20include%20for%20the%20body
```

We have already tried using `%0D%0A`, as well as a few other options, however none of those seem to work. Is there any way to add a new line through the URL or is that just not possible?

Comment: Why exact duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741510/new-line-in-gmail-app-for-ios-using-url-scheme

Comment: Facing same issue.Pls let me know is it possible from url schemes